# Translucent ray of light in three.js

Tags: three.js

we are trying to create a sphere/globe where we send out rays that are translucent. at the surface the ray is solid white but as it goes further into space it becomes more and more transparent. You can see in the image. What we have is at the moment shown on the left but what we want is depicted on the right. Also, we want the effect to be like a cone of light that disperses out the further it goes into space.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like [godrays](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=god#webgl_postprocessing_godrays)?

Comment: What have you already tried?